# Is there any speedup available on this code?

Tags: c++, simplify

I'm just guessing if there is any room for improving performance on this code:

```
std::vector<int>actualUvIndex(polyCount * 3, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < actualUvIndex.size(); i++)
{
    actualUvIndex[i] = i;
}

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
for (int group = 0; group < groupList.size(); group++)
{
    //take care per group only
    for (int si = 0; si < groupList[group].size(); si++)
    {
        //take care per vertex
        for (int v = 0; v < 3; v++)
        {
            int externalindex = groupList[group][si]->uvindex[v];

            //if it has been changed forget about it
            if (actualUvIndex[externalindex] == externalindex)
            {
                //compare with the rest of faces inside the group
                for (int sib = si + 1; sib < groupList[group].size(); sib++)
                {
                    for (int vb = 0; vb < 3; vb++)
                    {
                        int internalindex = groupList[group][sib]->uvindex[vb];
                        //if it has been changed forget about it
                        if (actualUvIndex[internalindex] == internalindex)
                        {
                            //if both uv vertex are equal just assign the same vertex index
                            if (groupList[group][sib]->uvs[vb][0] == groupList[group][si]->uvs[v][0] && groupList[group][sib]->uvs[vb][1] == groupList[group][si]->uvs[v][1])
                                actualUvIndex[internalindex] = externalindex;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me explain it a little:
I have my geometry (yes it is about 3d meshes) splitted in groups, so it has sense to isolate each one.

Each group contains faces and each face 3 vertex I can get the index of each vertex accessing the group->face->uvindex.

actualUvIndex is a vector to manage the index of each vertex.

Obviously my intention is to simplify and assign the first index found to redundant vertex meaning redundant the vertex that share their position that is stored in uvs[][0] and uvs[][1], notice that since that are uvs they only have two axis.

Regards and thank you advance for any tip.

Comment: you should head over to the codereview stackexchange. the question is more suited there

Comment: What platform are you running on?  What compiler and what compiler options are you using?

Comment: Right off the bat... `for (int i = 0; i < actualUvIndex.size(); i++) { actualUvIndex[i] = i; }` This whole thing can be replaced with [std::iota](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota), which will likely be more optimizable by the compiler. As an aside, don't use `int` to index into an array.

Comment: @Hayt never heard about that thank you!
AndrewHenle Win64 VisualStudio 2016 default options but OpenMP support.
erip thank you for the tip! anyway I think that it shouldn't be a big problem but the bottleneck is on the nested fors.

Answer (score 0):

You can speedup your code by using indexes for searching duplicated vertices. Define a has function for your vertice, then iterate over vertices and put them in-to a std::unordered map using vertice as a key and index as a value. When you put it, check if there is already a value for that key: if there is one, use the index from the map. That way complexity will be o(vertices number).

Comment: Unfortunatly the value are two floats so I cannot assign it as key.

Comment: You can use float as a key. It is not forbidden, it is just considered as a bad practice to compare floats for equality. But in your code you already do that: `groupList[group][sib]->uvs[vb][0] == groupList[group][si]->uvs[v][0]`. So std::unordered_set will be equivalent to your code. But if equality comparison is not suitable then the idea of speedup remains the same, but you will need another type of index. Something like k-d tree for example.